# How to access each element in Array of hashes created using Text::CSV_XS module

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, cpan

I have generated array of hash in the following format using Text::CSV_XS module

Output of Data Dumper:

```
$VAR1 = [
    {   'TITLE'       => 'test csv',
        'SEVERITY'    => '3',
        'Attachments' => 'dklsfj/dksfj.dskak/fsajk',
        'ID'          => '123',
        'STATUS'      => 'pending',
        'History'     => 'repeat',
        'priority'    => '4',
        'DESCRIPTION' => 'fdlkfjalskfjlskflafkdalsfjkasljfkldksajdfklsajkl',
        'PROJECT'     => 'hadkf'
    },
    {   'PROJECT'     => 'hadkf',
        'DESCRIPTION' => 'fdlkfjalskfjlskflafkdalsfjkasljfkldksajdfklsajkl',
        'priority'    => '4',
        'History'     => 'repeat',
        'ID'          => '124',
        'STATUS'      => 'pending',
        'Attachments' => 'dklsfj/dksfj.dskak/fsajk',
        'SEVERITY'    => '3',
        'TITLE'       => 'test csv'
    },
    {   'Attachments' => 'dklsfj/dksfj.dskak/fsajk',
        'ID'          => '125',
        'STATUS'      => 'pending',
        'SEVERITY'    => '3',
        'PROJECT'     => 'hadkf',
        'History'     => 'repeat',
        'priority'    => '4',
        'DESCRIPTION' => 'fdlkfjalskfjlskflafkdalsfjkasljfkldksajdfklsajkl',
        'TITLE'       => 'test csv'
    },
    {   'TITLE'       => 'test csv',
        'DESCRIPTION' => 'fdlkfjalskfjlskflafkdalsfjkasljfkldksajdfklsajkl',
        'History'     => 'repeat',
        'priority'    => '4',
        'PROJECT'     => 'hadkf',
        'SEVERITY'    => '3',
        'STATUS'      => 'pending',
        'ID'          => '126',
        'Attachments' => 'dklsfj/dksfj.dskak/fsajk'
    }
];
```

I am trying to print ID of the first array element as below

```
print "$aoh[0]{ID}";
```

but it returns the following error:

```
Not a HASH reference at csv_parse.pl line 12
```

I am new to using this module.Please let me know what the mistake is?

My code for generating the Array of hash is

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV_XS qw( csv );

open( my $fh, "<", "test.csv" ) or die "cannot open the file $!";
my @aoh = csv( { in => $fh, headers => "auto" } );
print Dumper(@aoh);
close($fh);
print "$aoh[0]{ID}";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it looks first element of `@aoh` is array reference, so either dereference what function returns,

```
my @aoh = @{ csv ({ in => $fh, headers => "auto" }) };
```

or

```
print "$aoh[0][0]{ID}";
```

or

```
my $aoh = csv ({ in => $fh, headers => "auto" });
print "$aoh->[0]{ID}";
```